# Error code for "not logged in" or page redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, forms-authentication

Is there an error code for handling users who are not logged in user but tries to enter a webpage by manually typing the URL?

Currently my web application redirects the user to the login page, but I would like to know if there is a better way to handle the page redirection to an error page in the web.config.

**EDIT:**

`Forms` tag in web.config:

`<forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/dataRefresh.aspx" timeout="20" />`

Comment: If *not authenticated* is meant to be an error in your application then you could simply edit the login page to show that. I assume you're looking for something like an "access denied" message?

Comment: @Yuck Yes, I am looking for a solution to redirect the user to show an error message instead of the login page. I have edited my post on my `forms` tag in the web.config.

Comment: Keep in miind a valid user might have bookmarked a page and be visiting it after their login has expired. If you don't forward them to the login page, be sure to do something that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You will need to in your Global.asax.cs, in the Application_EndRequest event handler</strike>

You will need to create an [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) that handles the EndRequest event and does the following processing:

```
    if(Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
    // add code to redirect to the access denied page
    }
```

Your HttpModule will need to be registered in front of the UrlAuthorizationModule so that you can do the redirect before the UrlAuthorizationModule does its own.

This will do this for all request that the forms authentication would have normally routed to the login page.

Comment: May I know how do I create `Global.asax.cs`? I do have a file with that name currently

Comment: @RUiHAO if you already have a file with that name you do not need to create it.  You can just add the handler to it.

Comment: @RUiHAO, right click on the project, add new item, choose Global Application Class (the file name should default to Global.asax, do not change it).

Comment: I managed to create the global.asax file, but the code you provided does not redirect my user to the error page when he tries to access a webpage w/o logging in, and is redirected to the login page instead.

Comment: if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/App/Error/NotLoggedIn.aspx");
        }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7989/discussion-between-jared-shaver-and-ruihao)